# PyTorch version can't satisfy the requirements

Tags: python, pip, pytorch

I've been trying to install the Buzz Transcriber for my speech-to-text project, but when I try to install it using `pip install "git+https://github.com/chidiwilliams/buzz.git"`, it appears that my PyTorch version does not satisfy the requirements.

```
Collecting git+https://github.com/chidiwilliams/buzz.git
  Cloning https://github.com/chidiwilliams/buzz.git to **(my user and directory)**
  Running command git clone --filter=blob:none --quiet https://github.com/chidiwilliams/buzz.git 'C:\Users\PERSONAL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-jpc1c0ac'
  Resolved https://github.com/chidiwilliams/buzz.git to commit 2567d7f65b021c467915198167025c20021115d4
  Running command git submodule update --init --recursive -q
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting PyQt6==6.4.0 (from buzz-captions==0.8.4)
  Using cached PyQt6-6.4.0-cp37-abi3-win_amd64.whl (6.4 MB)
Collecting appdirs<2.0.0,>=1.4.4 (from buzz-captions==0.8.4)
  Using cached appdirs-1.4.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (9.6 kB)
Collecting dataclasses-json<0.6.0,>=0.5.9 (from buzz-captions==0.8.4)
  Using cached dataclasses_json-0.5.14-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (22 kB)
Collecting faster-whisper<0.5.0,>=0.4.1 (from buzz-captions==0.8.4)
  Using cached faster_whisper-0.4.1-py3-none-any.whl (1.5 MB)
Collecting humanize<5.0.0,>=4.4.0 (from buzz-captions==0.8.4)
  Using cached humanize-4.8.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (7.8 kB)
Collecting keyring<24.0.0,>=23.13.1 (from buzz-captions==0.8.4)
  Using cached keyring-23.13.1-py3-none-any.whl (37 kB)
Collecting openai<0.28.0,>=0.27.1 (from buzz-captions==0.8.4)
  Using cached openai-0.27.10-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (13 kB)
Collecting openai-whisper==v20230124 (from buzz-captions==0.8.4)
  Using cached openai-whisper-20230124.tar.gz (1.2 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting platformdirs<4.0.0,>=3.5.3 (from buzz-captions==0.8.4)
  Using cached platformdirs-3.11.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (11 kB)
Collecting sounddevice<0.5.0,>=0.4.5 (from buzz-captions==0.8.4)
  Using cached sounddevice-0.4.6-py3-none-win_amd64.whl (199 kB)
Collecting stable-ts==1.0.2 (from buzz-captions==0.8.4)
  Using cached stable-ts-1.0.2.tar.gz (23 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of buzz-captions to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==1.12.1 (from buzz-captions) (from versions: 2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.1.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch==1.12.1
```

I've already tried installing the PyTorch versions mentioned in the `(from versions: 2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.1.0)` bit for it to install, but it's still not working.

Comment: What is your python version?

Comment: @Goku From `-cp37-abi3-win_amd64` I see it's Python 3.7, 64 bit, Windows. `torch==1.12.1` should install.

Comment: @Goku It's Python 3.9.0